# On join, bot gives pre determined role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a command the gets the ID of a role and stores it (joinrole)

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
   guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "joinrole"));
});
```

how do I define the joinrole and make the bot give that specific role

Comment: It's quite unclear for me what you want to achieve, can you post some relevant info? Code, errors, anything that can help readers understand your question and most important, answering your question?

Comment: Yes sorry let me edit the original post

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: Discord.js 12.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The `addRole` method is deprecated and removed in Discord.js V12.x. So you should use the `.add()` method to add roles on guild members. This code should do it:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
    const RoleToGiveNewMembers = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");

    if(RoleToGiveNewMembers) {
        /**
         * Role found
         * We found a role to give to the user.
        */
       guildMember.roles.add(RoleToGiveNewMembers);
    }
});
```

There is also a nice guide for upgrading and using Discord.js V12. [Updating from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).